# Would the following grammar be ambiguous?

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

I have the grammar $S = aSbS|bSaS|\varepsilon$. When I was first looking at the problem I thought it was unambiguous. When I looked at the answer it said that it was ambiguous. The solution it gave was:

$S \rightarrow aSbS \rightarrow a\varepsilon bS \rightarrow a\varepsilon b\varepsilon \rightarrow ab$

$S \rightarrow aSbS \rightarrow aSb\varepsilon \rightarrow a\varepsilon b\varepsilon \rightarrow ab$

This doesn't make sense to me though because aren't these both producing the same parse tree?

Comment: Test your grammar on: https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1156/tools/cfg/

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, both of those derivations produce the same parse tree.

A grammar is ambiguous iff it has two different *leftmost* derivations for a sentence. (Equivalently, if it has two different *rightmost* derivations.) Only one of the provided derivations is leftmost, so these two derivations do not constitute a demonstration of ambiguity.

The grammar *is* ambiguous, though:

$$\begin{align}&S\to aSbS \to abS \to abaSbS\to ababS \to abab\\
&S\to aSbS \to abSaSbS \to abaSbS \to ababS \to abab\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help.